# React application env config

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, config

I have a React application with the following contents in package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:int": "env-cmd -f .env.int npm start",
    "start:ua": "env-cmd -f .env.ua npm start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:int": "env-cmd -f .env.int npm run-script build",
    "build:ua": "env-cmd -f .env.ua npm run-script build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```

I have a few files:

```
.env.int
.env.ua
```

.env.int

```
REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID= xxx
REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID= yyy
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID= aaa
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI= abc.com
```

.env.ua

```
REACT_APP_AAD_UI_APP_CLIENT_ID= mmm
REACT_APP_AAD_API_APP_CLIENT_ID= nnn
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_TENANT_ID= bbb
REACT_APP_AAD_APP_SERVICE_BASE_URI= def.com
```

I have a YAML task to deploy a static web application:

```
- task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    name: DeployStaticWebApp
    displayName: Deploy Static Web App
    inputs:
      app_location: 'web-app'
      app_build_command: 'npm ci && npm run build:int'
      cwd: '${{ parameters.root }}/webapp_package'
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(deployment_token) # captured from deploymentOutputs
```

Is it possible to avoid adding the values in .env files (to avoid exposing secrets publicly) and get the .env values from pipeline variables or some other place?

In the above example,

> xxx, yyy, aaa, abc.com

> mmm, nnn, bbb, def.com

Comment: Sure, just set actual environment variables in your build environment

Comment: Example please on code updates in package.json and .env files while using pipeline variables.

Comment: There are none.